# How can I delete a topic from DCOS Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, marathon

We are running Kafka via DCOS.  We have a topic which appears to have some bad data.  I would like to delete that topic.

Tried running:
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper  --delete --topic

This said it had marked the topic for deletion but that it wouldn't work unless the "delete.topic.enable=true".  Tried setting that for each broker using:

dcos kafka broker update 1 --options delete.topic.enable=true`

And then restarted the brokers

The topic is still there and still marked for deletion.  How can I get the brokers to delete that topic?

Answer (score 1):

In order to override this parameter you need to add the following environment variable to the Kafka service :

```
KAFKA_OVERRIDE_DELETE_TOPICS=true
```

You can update this quite simply in the DCOS service definition, via edit button then Environment Variables form.

You'll notice it changes your configuration descriptor (json file) :

```
...
"env": {
   ...
   "KAFKA_OVERRIDE_DELETE_TOPICS": "true",
   ...
}
...
```

Once the service is restarted with this settings you can delete any topic using :

```
dcos kafka topic delete <topicname>
```